# Java method signature not splitting on configured line length

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Because of reasons I need to deal with some rather long class names that I can't change, and I also need to deal with a strict max line length of 100 characters. So far that went okay-ish, but now I've run into an issue where VS Code does not want to split the method signature:

```java
public class Clients {
  public SoapJmsRequestReply<GetBusinessPartnerDataRequestType, GetBusinessPartnerDataResponseType> getBusinessPartnerDataClient() {
    /* blabla */
  }
}
```

The 100 limit is reached at the `>` so I can't shorten the method name to get an acceptable line length. What our linter does accept is:

```java
public class Clients {
  public SoapJmsRequestReply<GetBusinessPartnerDataRequestType, GetBusinessPartnerDataResponseType>
      getBusinessPartnerDataClient() {
    /* blabla */
  }
}
```

But VS Code's formatter does not want to keep it that way and formats it back to the first example. Is there a configuration somewhere in the stylesheet xml to enable this line break to occur?

Answer (score 0):

try to set `editor.wordWrap` and `editor.wordWrapColumn` to your `settings.json`

```
"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 100
```